# Count number of words in HTML paragraphs

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML file which has a few paragraphs with the same class 'profile-value'. I would like to create a **word count** using JavaScript that can **count all words of each paragraph**. I've given this a go:

```
var profile_values = document.getElementsByClassName('profile-value');
var total_words = 0;
for (var i = 0; i > profile_values.length; i++) {
    total_words += profile_values[i].length;
};
```

The total is then called using innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById('word-count').innerHTML = total_words;
```

I have seen that iterating over Nodelists is rather nacky, but I have also tried converting the Nodelist into an array before trying out the above code, again to no avail. Hopefully you guys can shed some light on this?

Comment: just replace to `i < profile_values.length`

Comment: this seems to produce 'NaN', is there something else that I may be missing?

Comment: There's no `length` property for that object (`profile_values[i]`). The solution will also depend on whether your elements nest other elements or if it only holds the text inside.

Comment: yeah, use `profile_values[i].innerText.length;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? https://jsfiddle.net/rrex0gju/

```
function getWordCounts(nodeList) {
    var wordCount = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++ ) {
        wordCount += nodeList[i].textContent.trim().split(' ').length;
    }
    return wordCount;
}

document.querySelector('span').textContent = getWordCounts(document.querySelectorAll('p'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` property of string and then get `length` to get total number of words.

Here `trim()` function is used to remove **leading** and **trailing** space from string.

```js
var profile_values = document.getElementsByClassName('profile-value');
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < profile_values.length; i += 1){
  total += profile_values[i].innerHTML.trim().split(" ").length
}
alert(total);
```

```html
<p class="profile-value">    sdfsf dsfsf dsfs sdfds      </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the paragraphs as following

```
var paras = document.getElementsByClassName('profile-value');
```

Then run the snippet to get the count as following:

```
var count = 0;
for(var i=0; i<paras.length; i++){
 var content = paras[i].textContent;
 var words = content.match(/\S+/g);
 count += words? words.length : 0;
}
console.log('count = ', count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the above responses, I've changed the code to read:

```
var profile_values = document.getElementsByClassName('profile-value');
var total_words = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < profile_values.length; i++) {
  total_words = total_words + profile_values[i].innerText.split("   ").length;

};
```

This seems to have done the trick. Does this seem correct to you guys?
I would like to thank you all for your help!

Comment: Could you please vote an answer to mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Access all classes *profile_value*:

```
var profile_values = document.querySelectorAll(".profile_value");
```

Profile_values is now a **HTML collection**. Go through the collection:

```
[].forEach.call(profile_values, function(paragraph) {});
```

In the *inner* function **split** the **innerText** into an **array** with **all the words**. The length of the array is the number of the words of the recent paragraph:

```
var splitted = paragraph.innerText.split(" ");
var countWordsParagraph = splitted.length;
```

Add countWordsParagraph to totalWordCount:

```
totalWordCount += countWordsParagraph;
```

Complete:

```
var profile_values = document.querySelectorAll('.profile-value'); 
var totalWordCount = 0;
[].forEach.call(profile_values, function(paragraph) {
    var splitted = paragraph.innerText.split(" ");
    var countWordsParagraph = splitted.length;
    totalWordCount += countWordsParagraph;
});
```

[Visible](https://jsfiddle.net/zuyuneLy/1/)